# Show that M is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, self-learning, martingales

Assume that $E[(HM)_N]=0$ for predictable process H and $H_0=0$. I want to prove that $M$ is a martingale.

$$(HM)_N= \sum_{j=1}^N H_j (M_j -M_{j-1})+ H_0M_0 = \sum_{j=1}^N H_j (M_j -M_{j-1})$$

I am stuck at showing that $M$ is a martinagle.

I read some theorems. (If required, I can share them) but I couldn’t not show this proof. Please help me to do this.

Many thanks.

Comment: You assume that $\mathbb{E}[(HM)_N)=0$ for **any** predictable process with $H_0=0$?

Comment: Yes you are right. Under the assumption, I would like to prove M is martinagle. @saz could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the underlying filtration. Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and pick $F \in \mathcal{F}_n$. The process

$$H_j := \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if $j \neq n+1$}, \\ 1_F, & \text{if $j=n+1$},\end{cases}$$ is predictable and $H_0=0$. We have

$$(H \bullet M)_{n+1} = \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} H_j (M_j-M_{j-1}) = H_{n+1} (M_{n+1}-M_n) = 1_F (M_{n+1}-M_n).$$

By assumption, the random variable has expectation zero, i.e.

$$0 = \mathbb{E}((H \bullet M)_{n+1}) = \mathbb{E}(1_F M_{n+1})-\mathbb{E}(1_F M_n),$$

and so

$$\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1} 1_F) = \mathbb{E}(M_n 1_F).$$

Since this holds for any $F \in \mathcal{F}_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it follows that $(M_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer!

Comment: I don't see how $\mathbb E[M_{n+1}\mathsf 1_F] = \mathbb E[M_n\mathsf 1_F]$ for all $F\in\mathcal F_n$ implies the martingale condition
$$
\mathbb E[M_{n+1}\mid \mathcal F_n] = M_n.
$$
Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Math1000 Recall that $Y = \mathbb{E})(X \mid \mathcal{F})$ if $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and $$\forall F \in \mathcal{F}\::\: \int_F Y \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_F X \, d\mathbb{P}.$$ Equivalently, the integral condition reads $$\mathbb{E}(1_F Y) = \mathbb{E}(1_F X).$$ That's exactly the condition which I verified.

Comment: @saz Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Put $Y=H\cdot M$. Since $H$ is predictable and $(M_j-M_{j-1})_j$ is adapted, clearly $Y$ is adapted. Now, for each positive integer $N$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[(H\cdot M)_N] &= \mathbb E\left[\sum_{j=1}^N H_j(M_j-M_{j-1}) \right]\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^N \mathbb E[H_j(M_j-M_{j-1})]\\
&=0,
\end{align}
which implies that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^N \mathbb E[H_jM_j] = \sum_{j=1}^N \mathbb E[H_jM_{j-1}].
$$
For $N=1$ this yields $\mathbb E[H_1M_1] = \mathbb E[H_1M_0]$, and by induction $\mathbb E[H_jM_j] = \mathbb E[H_jM_{j-1}]$, $j\geqslant 1$. I am not sure how to proceed from here, but hopefully this was useful.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is also very useful and understandable.